# ROS how to find all executables of a package?

Tags: ros

I want to ask how to find all the executable names of a package in ROS (Robot Operating System)? For example, find `spawn_model` in `gazebo_ros` package. When I inspect the package in my system, it just shows some `.xml`, `.cmake` files, without any executables. But I can run it, such as: `rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to type: "rosrun name_of_package " and then press tab two times, it should show you all the executables built.

Answer (score 5):

After looking in the bash autocompletion script for `rosrun`, it looks like the command `catkin_find` is used to find the location of the executables for a package, and the executables are filtered with a `find` command.

If you want to create a script to give you a list of the executables follow the instructions below:

Save the following script in a file called `rospack-list-executables`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "usage: $(basename $0) <pkg_name>"
    echo ""
    echo "       To get a list of all package names use the command"
    echo "          'rospack list-names'"
    exit
fi

pkgname=${1}

pkgdir="$(catkin_find --first-only --without-underlays --libexec ${pkgname})"


if [[ -n "${pkgdir}" ]]; then
    find -L "${pkgdir}" -executable -type f ! -regex ".*/[.].*" ! -regex ".*${pkgdir}\/build\/.*" -print0 | tr '\000' '\n' | sed -e "s/.*\/\(.*\)/\1/g" | sort
else
    echo "Cannot find executables for package '${pkgname}'." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Then make the `rospack-list-executables` script executable (`chmod +x rospack-list-executables`) and place it in a directory that can be found in your `$PATH` environment variable.

Run the script:

```
$ rospack-list-executables gazebo_ros
debug
gazebo
gdbrun
gzclient
gzserver
libcommon.sh
perf
spawn_model
```

You should get the same result that you get when you type the `rosrun <pkgname>` command and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
$ rosrun gazebo_ros 
debug         gazebo        gdbrun        gzclient      gzserver      libcommon.sh  perf          spawn_model
```

You can check the executables for all packages with the following bash code:

```
rospack list-names | while read pkgname; do
    echo "Executables for package '${pkgname}':";
    rospack-list-executables $pkgname; echo "";
done
```

To enable package autocompletion for your newly created command, type the following:

```
complete -F _roscomplete rospack-list-executables
```

If you do not want to have to type the `complete` command every time you login, you can append it to your `.bashrc` file:

```
echo "complete -F _roscomplete rospack-list-executables" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now when you type the command `rospack-list-executables` and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, you should get a list of all the available packages to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

For ROS**2**, you can use

```
ros2 pkg executables --full-path
```

To get the path of a package, you can use

```
ros2 pkg prefix cpp_pubsub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catkin_find --first-only --without-underlays --libexec <your package name>)
```

should give you the folder where the executables are